# redirecionando para um site usando um botão (kivy)

Tags: python-kivy

Ola !  Estou fazendo um aplicativo simples, mas que precisa de um redirecionamento para um site especifico !
Exemplo:
Com apenas um toque, o botão redireciona o usuário para o YouTube !
Estou fazendo meu aplicativo de desktop, usando o Pycharm, mais orientado ao arquivo KV...
Caso saiba de algo parecido na documentação, um codigo no Github, ou alguma pergunta respondida o Reddit, 
não exite em falar para mim !
Obrigado !

Answer (score 0):

**Você pode usar webbrowser Exemplo:**

```
import webbrowser

def abrir_site(*args):

 site = 'https://www.youtube.com'
 webbrowser.open_new(site)


botao = Button(text='You Tube',on_release=abrir_site)


class app(App):

 def build(self): return botao

app().run()
```